# How can I upgrade R version in SQL server 2017?

Tags: r, sql-server-2017

I want to use silhouette_kproto function from clustmixType library of R in SQL Server 2017.But it not working for current version of R. Can I just upgrade the R version to be used in SQL server?

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/install/upgrade-r-and-python?view=sql-server-2017 you can go from the initial R 3.3.3 to R 3.4.3. I am not sure if this is sufficient, since I do not know why the function you mention does not work in your case.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot upgrade the R version to anything higher than 3.4.3 for SQL Server 2017, as per what @Ralf Stubner says in his comment.

This is related to the other components that make part of SQL Server Machine Learning Services, (SqlSatellite, BxlServer, etc.).

To see how to upgrade look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/install/upgrade-r-and-python?view=sql-server-2017), (link to MS docs).

Comment: The highest version for 2017 is now 3.5.2.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/install/change-default-language-runtime-version?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks for that @wibeasley! There are by the way exciting changes happening in the SQL Server R world. Goin g forward we'll be able to use CRAN R instead of Microsoft's R (MRO). The post here discusses it a bit more: https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2021/06/30/looking-to-the-future-for-r-in-azure-sql-and-sql-server/.